# How to make TFOOT to show only at the end of the table

Tags: html, html-table

I have an html table with a large number of rows and when I'm trying to print it, the content in TFOOT is showing in every page break. Can I make it to show only at the end of the table in the last page?

Note: I can't remove the tfoot from the table because the table is output from CGridView of yii framework which I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m afraid it can’t be done except with scripting. By default, the `tfoot` element has [`display: table-footer-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#value-def-table-footer-group), which means that it appears after any other rows of the table *and* may be repeated at the end of each page (if the browser wants to do that). You cannot separate these two things in current CSS.

If you set `tfoot { display: table-row-group }`, it won’t be repeated, but it won’t appear at the end of the table but in the same place as in the HTML source, which means that it is at the start, before normal rows, by HTML 4 syntax. I’m assuming it’s there in the HTML code and you cannot change this. (In fact `tfoot` can be placed last in the table markup, and HTML5 allows this.)

You can get rid of the footer altogether by setting `tfoot { display: none }`, but I presume you don’t want that.

If client-side scripting can be used here, then you could set `display` to `table-row-group` together with code that simply moves the `tfoot` element last in the table. Assuming the `table` element has `id`, say `id=tbl`, you can use the following script (which also sets `display`):

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
var foot = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0];
foot.style.display = 'table-row-group';
tbl.removeChild(foot);
tbl.appendChild(foot);
```

If the `table` element lacks `id`, you need some different way to find the element in JavaScript, depending on the structure of the page. If it is the only, or the first, `table` element there, you can replace the first line above by

```
var tbl = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
```

Comment: `tbl.tFoot` is a shorter alternative to `gEBTN`,