# How to add border at the bottom of each paginated table with CSS?

Tags: html, css, pagination

I have a big list of data inside HTML table that is fed from the database, which then printout to PDF. The table just ordinary table, with couple of columns, but the style I use has border left and right to show the vertical line on each table on every page, but not the horizontal like. I use CSS to draw the border, something like this:

```
td {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

The problem I got is when paginated (printed to PDF) on each page at the bottom of the table, it wasn't closed so it looks open. I want to close the border at the bottom of the table of each page.

I managed to draw the border of the last row using tfoot, this works great until I got to the very last page, apparently it also draw it there too. Don't want it to draw at the end because I've made a summary there already, so having the line there is just not good.

```
<thead>...some header...</thead>
<tfoot>
  <tr><td class=myborder>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>...list of data (100 rows of tr)...</tbody>
```

The CSS, I use red for hightlight on my table:

```
.myborder {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

So my question is there any css that can draw the simple line at each page ending but not at the last page?

If using tfoot, I've tried looking for solution, it pretty much like the post below, but a bit different, I don't want tfoot to show on the last page, but any other page is fine.

[How to make TFOOT to show only at the end of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898409/how-to-make-tfoot-to-show-only-at-the-end-of-the-table)

Thanks in advance.

PS. Thanks Ben for the format fixes, this is my first post :)

Comment: No problem, did the replacement of `<foot>` with `<tfoot>` help?

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your question and while formatting I noticed at least a misplaced `<td>` in your `<tfoot>`. Also you're opening with `<foot>`, which should be `<tfoot>`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this to apply for all tfoot except the last child.

```
tfoot:not(:last-child):after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

First answer, correct me if there is any mistake.

Comment: Thanks Wee Hui Pheng for the answer but unfortunately it's not working for me. I'm using MPDF to generate the PDF, and I found that the fancy thing like that isn't working on all the CSS. I tried using nth-child(odd) too so the background color for all the odd rows different than the even rows, also not working. I'm guessing MPDF isn't up to that (yet).

Comment: the MPDF version I'm using is 5.7.4